# How can I pass NULL as an argument in R?

Tags: r, null

I have a vector `arguments`, where some values are `NA`. I would like to pass these arguments sequentially to a function like this:

```
myFunction(argument = ifelse(!is.na(arguments[i]),
           arguments[i], NULL))
```

so that it will take the value in `arguments[i]` whenever it's not `NA`, and take the default `NULL` otherwise. But this generates an error.

If it makes any difference, the function in question is `match_on()`, from the `optmatch` package. The argument in question is `caliper`, because I would like to provide a caliper only when one is available (i.e. when the value in the vector of calipers is not `NA`). And the error message is this:

```
Error in ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no,  length.out = length(ans))[!test &  : 
replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Comment: why can't you do the `NA` check inside the function once you receive the arguments?

Comment: NULL and NA are two very different things. NULL is a kind of object.   Also the way to check ifsomething is NA is not NA is to use `!is.na(arguments)`.   Also ` ifelse()` is vectorized, so I'm not sure why you are using an index  .. is the ifelse inside a loop?    You need to provide somemore context.  However changingfrom NA to NULL is not something that really makes sense in R.

Comment: Use if and else.

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I suppose I could modify the source code of `match_on()` like you suggest, but I was asking if there is a way to fix my one line of code.

Comment: @Elin I always forget about the `!is.na()` thing, thanks. And, yes, the idea is to have that function in a loop and have it sequentially work with the values of `arguments`. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Roland that is definitely a valid answer but... any way to do it within the function call like I was trying to?

Comment: argument = if ... else ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `?switch()` instead of `ifelse` -

```
myFunction(argument = switch(is.na(arguments[i]) + 1, arguments[i], NULL))
```

Here's the help doc for `switch` -

> switch(EXPR, ...)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> EXPR   an expression evaluating to a number or a character string.
>
> ... the list of alternatives. If it is intended that EXPR has a
>   character-string value these will be named, perhaps except for one
>   alternative to be used as a ‘default’ value.
>
> **Details**
>
> switch works in two distinct ways depending whether the first argument
>   evaluates to a character string or a number.
>
> If the value of EXPR is not a character string it is coerced to
>   integer. If the integer is between 1 and nargs()-1 then the
>   corresponding element of ... is evaluated and the result returned:
>   thus if the first argument is 3 then the fourth argument is evaluated
>   and returned

Basically, when argument is `NA` then `EXPR` evaluates to 2 which returns `NULL` and when it is not `NA` then `EXPR` evaluates to 1 and returns `arguments[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `do.call`

```
do.Call(
  myFunction,
  list(
    argument = ifelse(!is.na(arguments[i]), arguments[i], NULL),
    # `...`
  )
)
```

You don't need the if-else statement because lists accept named NULL values (provided that i < lenght(arguments)).

```
do.Call(
  myFunction,
  list(
    argument  = arguments[i],
    # `...`
  )
)
```